# Recovering a partition after being reallocated

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, mate-desktop, testdisk

I have two partitions, c and d. Recently, I've decided to install Linux Ubuntu on the machine, and intended to do that on the c drive. It seems however that I messed up something during the installation, which has caused formatting the entire hard drive, and merging it into only one partition. Now, after logging into Ubuntu, I can see that there is only one partition with around 500 GB (the whole drive) where the OS is installed.

The question is whether it is possible to recover the d drive. At the moment, I'm checking [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and running a deep search, however, I'm not very optimistic. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

TestDisk is the way to go. Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
and follow the steps. If you can, use a different computer to browse and ask for advice and stop using your machine. Normal use of your computer can overwrite the data that you are trying to recover.

Comment: It should be added that "TestDisk is the way to go" only because OP overwrote the partition table and not parts of the second partition, i.e. the one that needs to be recovered. Otherwise TestDisk may not be enough.